# pushing object parameter into a array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Hai guys can anyone please help me in this . i want to push a object parameter (common in every object of array)into a array of objects
below is my code:

```
    { 
     RetractReason: null,
     StartDate:"2017-03-20T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
```

Comment: please format the code

Comment: do a simple loop & update the format & then insert into the scope variable

Comment: any example ??????

Comment: Thanks for providing the hundreds of lines of data. That will be of great help in solving the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try for loop

```
var myarray = [{StartDate:new Date(),Name:'a'},{StartDate:new Date(),Name:'b'}];

console.log(myarray);

myarray.forEach(function(item){
    item.StartDate = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1))
})

console.log(myarray);
```

you will find update new Date there just add this to console

Comment: If you share your array I will update my code as that way. Thank you.

Comment: you are genius bro. y bcoz am provided 100s of lines but you rectified my doubt thank u so much. i got solution

Comment: anytime @vamsi :)

Comment: if you don't mine can i ask doubts frequently ?? if yes can you provide your facebook or whatsapp contact ???

Comment: sure @vamsi . you can find me at facebook.com/athulnairr